# Does the root formula differ for a higher order poly?

Tags: polynomials

Does the root formula differ for a higher order system?

I know that a the discriminant differs for a higher order system, but does the root formula from its standard second order system form differ for an increasing order? I am quite sure it does, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does differ a lot.

Remember that for, the solution of a quadratic equation, you complete the square and arrive to the classical expression which involves the discriminant.

Already, for a cubic or quartic polynomial, the approach is quite different (even if a discriminant is involved). I suggest you have a look at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

And, as you probably know, there is no explicit solution for general polynomials of degree five or higher

Comment: hmm... well i was looking for method where i could setup a range for where i want my root to lie, and thereby  determine the value of k for (x - k) (ax^2 + bx + c), for which  the poly would have the roots where i wanted to. But those examples seems a bit more complex to handle than thought.

Comment: For cases where there is an ovious root, you are perfectly right and this could apply to polynomials of any order. But, I was just addressing the most general case where you cannot find any root. Just a simple case $x^3+3 x^2+2 x+1=0$. Have fun ! Cheers.

Comment: my idea was to alter the original roots from the second order equation, by multiplying $(x \pm k)$ but that does not alter the original roots, but just add another one at $\mp k$

Comment: You are right ! But, all my congratulations for having tried ! Continue this way ! Stay curious ! Cheers. ):